# c# List manipulation

Tags: c#, list, list-manipulation

If I have

```
List<String> text
```

how can I create a sub-list of all continious elements within a specific range e.g.

```
List<String> subList = /* all elements within text bar the first 2*/
```

Also are there any other useful List manipulation tips & tricks that might be useful?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work even without LINQ:

```
List<String> subList = text.GetRange(2, text.Count - 2);
```

**Edit:** Fixed a typo.

Answer (score 8):

```
subList = text.Skip(2).ToList()
```

Skip(n) returns an IEnumerable<> with all elements except the first n.

When you really need a list after that, ToList() converts it back.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on 3.5, then there are a lot of new and interesting methods available on List. Just check out the section 'Extension methods' here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hw1as6.aspx